# How to configure correctly Firebase and get data in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Recently, I am learning React by following closely some tutorials but I have reached a point where my web application is stuck because I have not set up correctly the integration between ReactJS and Firebase and not get data for me. This is what I have so far.

**firebaseconfig**

```
import firebase from "firebase"

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    
    aapiKey: "AIzaSyBgkd-S5YDJM5ZdMy4jv6B3lyI-ICwiJP8",
    authDomain: "fecebook-messanger-clone.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fecebook-messanger-clone.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fecebook-messanger-clone",
    storageBucket: "fecebook-messanger-clone.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "504219440010",
    appId: "1:504219440010:web:dbb3bfcc715ddcf4a26e73",
    measurementId: "G-XSYZEK2EF7"

});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default  db ;
```

and the code in ***App.js*** :

````
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import {Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input } from '@material-ui/core';
    import Message from './Message';
    import db from './firebase'
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    
    function App() {
      const [input, setInput] = useState('');
      const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
      const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
      console.log(input);
      console.log(messages);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        //run once when the app component load
        db.collection('messages').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        })
      }, [])
    
      useEffect(() => {
       setUsername (prompt('Please enter your name ?'))
      }, [])
    
      const sendMessage = (event) => {
        // all the logic to send message goes
        event.preventDefault();
        db.collection('messages').add({
          message: input,
          username: username,
          timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() 
        })
    
        //setMessages([...messages, { username: username, message: input}])
        setInput('');
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello Issam :) </h1>
          <h2>Welcome {username}</h2>
    
         <form>
         <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">Enter a message ...</InputLabel>
          <Input value={input} onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}/>
          <Button disabled={!input} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={sendMessage}>Send Message</Button>
         </FormControl>
    
         
         </form>
          
    
          { /* message themsleves */}
          {
            messages.map((message) => (
              <Message username={username} message={message} />
            ))
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes bro !! i am sloving this problem When you look at my Firestore rules, they should match :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling firebase.initializeApp with "aapiKey" instead of "apiKey". That may be the problem

Comment: yes bro !! i am sloving this problem When you look at my Firestore rules, they should match :  `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I didn't understood your comment, could you explain better what you meant? Does this worked? Are you facing another problem?

Comment: Makes the changes in my database rules like the following one.                          
`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: allow read, write: if false. I have used this rules for that scheme but then its not working

Comment: I still dont understand the problem